# macOS Apache's localhost is showing 403 forbidden

Tags: macos, apache

I used to use Xampp and it takes a lot of time to start it. 
I've learned that the macOS comes with in-built apache and I've uninstalled XAMPP. When I start the server with "sudo apachectl start" and get into "localhost", I get a 403 forbidden page.

I see that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134880/mac-apache-localhost-giving-403-forbidden) questions raises similar issue but its solution is related to the changes that OP made to his system.

Comment: It could be many things. Check your apache config, look at your access and error logs, and it may give you a hint as to what's going on.

Comment: actually the folder "/private/var/log/apache2/" is empty... and I am not that of a pro to understand whats going on from the config file.